# prevent javascript on browser back button in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have called a javascript code from server side.It works fine but now once user use browser back button and comes to my page,Javascript code(i.e.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript) is called again.
How can I prevent that from happening.I believe something in page load.
Can someone please check and help.

Below is my code.

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.ADDMsg.Visible = false;
        string dropdownvalue = HiddenField.Value;
        this.ADDMsg.Text = "";
        bool flag = true;
        try
        {

            if (flag)
            {
                if (this.vpsReq == null)
                {
                    this.vpsReq = new VPSRequest();
                    try
                    {

                        this.Record_Request_VPS(this.vpsReq, dropdownvalue);


                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowStatus", "javascript:alert('Request Submitted');", true);


                    }
                    catch (Exception exception2)
                    {
                        this.ADDMsg.Text = exception2.Message;

                    }

                }
                else
                {

                }


            }
            else
            {
                this.ADDMsg.Text = "Please correct the errors above and click <i>Submit</i>.";
            }

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
        }

    }
```

and page load is :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtFrom.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("isPostBack", "1");
        }



        clnImplDate = txtFrom.Text;
        User = new User();

        try
        {
            User = (User)this.Session["User"];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        if ((User.UserID == null) || (User.UserID == ""))
        {
            User = Utility.GetUserInfo(User);
        }

        this.Session["User"] = User;

    }
```

Also,the usage of ispostback variable is shown below(Thought t o add this code for more clarity).

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var isPostBackObject = document.getElementById('isPostBack');
        if (isPostBackObject == null) {
            $('#<%= ADDMsg.ClientID %>').hide();
        }
        $("#" + "ClaimVEBP").hide();
        });
```

Any Solution ?even with jQuery is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following block of code in your page_load event handler like that:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("isPostBack", "1");
}
```

> !Postback
>    means that the Clientscript will run only in the first loading of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply  but still same problem.once I came back using browser back button,I got popup saying "Request Submitted'"